# Languages with homophonous IF-clauses

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, comparative-linguistics, conditionals

In English, most grammars tacitly or explicitly recognise two types of *if*. One of these introduces subordinate interrogative clauses:

- I don't know [**if** I  passed the exam].

The other introduces conditional protases:

- My dad will be over the moon [**if** I passed the exam].

Apart from the apparent difference in meaning, the clearest difference between these two occurrences of *if* is syntactic. The clauses introduced by so-called interrogative *if* appear as Complements and the clauses introduced by so-called conditional *if* appear Adjuncts [read 'Modifiers' or 'Adverbials'].

This homophony between  the items used to mark conditional protases and interrogative clauses is not a peculiarity of English, but occurs in many languages: Tagalog, American Sign Language and Spanish, for example.

However there is, it has been argued, a third *if* in English. This  *if* introduces clauses whose internal syntax makes them seem more like conditional protases and less like interrogative clauses (chiefly because such clauses allow the use of irrealis-*were*). These clauses, however, appear not as Adjuncts within conditional constructions but as Complements, often within extraposition constructions (bolding etc in the following added by me):

- It would be a shame [**if** Bob left]. (Williams 1974, p. 158)
- It would be wonderful [**if** unicorns existed].  (Pullum 1987, p. 260)

In the examples above we see a meaningless dummy pronoun *it* functioning as Subject. The *if*-clauses concerned appear as Complements (here, of predicate adjectives) within the VP, but are interpreted, semantically, as subjects. As described by Pullum (1987), on their most likely readings, the examples above mean something like *For Bob to leave would be a shame* and *For unicorns to exist would be wonderful*.

Some other examples:

- Can you imagine [**if** people really believed that]? (Rocchi 2011, p. 1)
- I'd prefer (it) [**if** you came on Thursday].

**The question**

1. Are there other languages where clauses which seem to have the same form as conditional protases occur in other environments, for example as the complements of verbs, adjectives or prepositions?
2. If so, are any of those languages ones where conditional protases may be introduced by the same items as interrogative clauses?

---

**<sup>References:</sup>**

<sup>Pullum, Geoffrey K. 1987. Implications of English extraposed irrealis clauses. In: Ann
Miller and Joyce Powers (eds.), *ESCOL ’87: Proceedings of the Fourth Eastern
Conference on Linguistics*, October 2-4, 1987, 260–70. Columbus, Ohio: The Ohio
State University.</sup>

<sup>Rocchi, Manuela. 2010. *A third* If. University of Edinburgh MSc dissertation.</sup>

<sup>Williams, Edwin. 1974. *Rule ordering in syntax*. Unpublished Doctoral dissertation, MIT.</sup>

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only languages I can think of where protasis-_if_ and this ‘third _if_’ **don’t** always coincide in form are languages where protasis and apodosis are not freely switchable, like Chinese; and even there, I think at least the first two examples would still be formally like conditionals, while the latter two are just not distinctly possible at all (i.e., can’t be distinguished from ‘can you imagine people really believing that?’). In languages where interrogative and conditional _if_ are distinct, ‘third _if_’ aligns with conditional _if_ in all cases I can think of.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks very much! Could you possibly name-drop a few of those languages, please?

Comment: For the group of languages where ‘third _if_’ would not coincide with the others? Definitely Chinese, and I think also Japanese – I don’t think _if_ clauses as object-like complements are possible at all in either (except to the extent that Japanese can always just make anything a nominal by conversion). Interrogative protases are just embedded regular interrogatives there, though (à la “I don’t know [did I pass the exam?]”), so perhaps those aren’t really good examples after all…

Comment: As for other languages that have the same alignment as English: definitely all the other Germanic languages (English is more or less alone in having interrogative = conditional, but all have conditional = ‘third’) as well as the Romance ones, which have int. = cond. = ‘third’. Goidelic and Finnic languages have cond. ≠ int. (int. are embedded as in Chinese/Japanese); in Goidelic, ‘third’ = cond., and I _think_ the same is true in Finnic, but I’m not entirely sure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Very interesting (and very helpful). Thank you :)

Comment: All the examples have modals in them. Is that a feature of the construction?

Comment: @jlawler Good question. Williams,, who so far as I know was the first scholar to write about them seemed to think so. Pullum also implies this, but doesn't state it. I'm not so sure, however. *Imagine* doesn't require a modal, and sentences such as *It's difficult if they don't respond straight away* seem to have a dummy and not a referential *it*. Aslo sentences such as "She hates (it) if you leave without saying goodbye" seem similar. Note the following seems okish "Which books is it useful if we keep"? which seems to show that that there  *if*-clause is a complement.

Comment: Like the Billy Crystal line _%I hate when that happens_.

Comment: BTW, the "first kind of _if_" is just a shorter version of _whether_, the _wh_-word for embedded yes/no questions. Since they're binary, _if_ fills the bill as well as _whether_, and is one syllable shorter to boot. If you wanna call it Complementizer _if_ or _WH if_, go ahead.

Comment: @jlawler Conditional *if* is binary too when you think of it. What I think I've found out from my reading and own investigations syntax-wise re *if/whether* is that while *whether* patterns like other *wh* words, *if* does not, or rather not so well. So, for example, *whether*-clauses can appear clause-initially in larger clauses and *if*-clauses can't; *wh*-words can appear at the front of infinitival clauses, *if* only introduces tensed clauses (or reductions of tensed clauses). Interestingly, I think I've isolated a few instances where conditional *if* is indistinguishable from *whether*.

Comment: @jlawler (By which I mean you can substitute in *whether* for conditional *if*, without any *or not*s etc).

Comment: @Araucaria-him I agree; and them both being _Wh_-words makes for parallel construction, too.